# Script to automat import of CSV into PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql, csv-import

I need to import a huge number of CSV files into Postgres (Linux). Does anybody know how I can write a script to automate this process?

I am a complete novice. Please help!

Comment: Hello geek2000 and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not adequately formulated to receive any help on this forum. Please review the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit this question or post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a shell script like loop.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

files=`ls *.sql`

for file in $files
do
  echo $file
  psql database-name < $file
done
```

Make the script executable by

```
chmod 0755 loop.sh
```

and run it

```
./loop.sh
```

Comment: kometen, the user want to automate the import of CSV files, not SQL files.

Comment: This is meant as an example.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Below command may be useful to you

```
psql -h host -d dbname -U user -c "\copy tablename from 'data.csv' with csv"
```

its working successfully in windows

I don't know the linux commands but loop suggested by kometen may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! appreciate it.